# MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE error

Tags: mysql, file-io, load

I try to load data into a certain column into a table with the following SQL-statement:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'filelist.txt' INTO TABLE filelist (filepath) LINES TERMINATED BY '#';
```

The structure of the data in each line is like this:

```
file:://///...path...txt#
```

and I get the following error message:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax near 'LINES TERMINATED BY '#'
```

I really don't know what is wrong. Anyone any ideas?

Comment: That is the name of the column in table filelist where I want the filepaths to be stored.

Comment: Try removing the 'LINES TERMINATED BY '#' from your sql-statement. Run this "LOAD DATA INFILE 'filelist.txt' INTO TABLE filelist (filepath)" only.

Comment: You were right. It worked. Thx. Filepaths are truncated if too long but that is another issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the 'LINES TERMINATED BY '#' from your sql-statement. Run this "LOAD DATA INFILE 'filelist.txt' INTO TABLE filelist (filepath)" only ... from comment